# Lock Less Key Value data structure

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, data-structures, key-value, lockless

I need a data structure to store 500k keys, each one with some associated data. 150 Threads will be running concurrently & accessing the keys. Once in a day I need to update the data structure since there may be some manipulation operation, say the key is deleted, new key is added or the data is changed.
When the data structure updation is in progress I can not block any of the 150 threads from accessing it.
I don't want to use current hash implementations like memcache or redis since the number of keys may grow in future & I want in-memory access for faster lookup?
Instead will prefer some data structure implementation in C/C++.

Comment: the simple way is to store the keys in a database and read the keys whenever needed.

Comment: If the update is only once in a day, why not copy - modify - replace(swap)? That is, making it immutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Userspace RCU](https://lttng.org/urcu) library contains a set of concurrent data structures implemented with the help of RCU. Among those a lock-free resizable hash table based on the articles

- Ori Shalev and Nir Shavit. Split-ordered lists: Lock-free
  extensible hash tables. J. ACM 53, 3 (May 2006), 379-405.
- Michael, M. M. High performance dynamic lock-free hash tables
  and list-based sets. In Proceedings of the fourteenth annual ACM
  symposium on Parallel algorithms and architectures, ACM Press,
  (2002), 73-82.

For more information you can see the comments in the implementation at http://git.lttng.org/?p=userspace-rcu.git;a=blob;f=rculfhash.c

Answer (score 1):

LMDB can handle this http://symas.com/mdb/ Since it uses MVCC, writers don't block readers. You can update whatever/whenever and your 150 reader threads will run just fine. LMDB reads perform no blocking operations whatsoever, and scale perfectly linearly across any number of CPUs.

(Disclaimer: I am the author of LMDB)